# как sf2 файл держать в памяти и не загружать при повторном проигрывании

Tags: flutter, dart

использую библиотеку `flutter_midi` но при его использовании столкнулся с такой проблемой как асинхронные методы, при `initState` использую метод `FlutterMidi.prepare` и когда что то на экране происходит, например, при нажатии кнопки, использую метод `FlutterMidi.playMidiNote` но все равно этот метод является асинхронным и имеется задержка, как можно эту проблему решить чтобы при нажатии кнопки не было никаких задержек, это очень нужно для моего приложения, спасибо!

Comment: Там проблема скорее всего с Platform Channel... Как вариант попробуйте собрать release сборку и посмотреть, возможно задержка будет не такой заметной.

Comment: задержка очень заметная, попробовал как вы советовали видимо проблема в  `MethodChannel('flutter_midi').invokeMethod('play_midi_note', mapData);` этот метод куда то отправляет `mapData`(т.е midi), получает ответа от него и из за этого случаются задержки, не поминаю тогда зачем метод `prepare` нужен если все равно случаются задержки

Comment: Да, к сожалению это уже не исправить...